# Indicating end of Standard Input

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, shell, stdin

How does one indicate that one has finished entering test in stdin?

For example, let's say that I wish to encrypt 'blue' using MD5 (I know MD5 is unsecure, but just for this example). I tried

```
user$ blue | md5
```

which I was led to understand is how one pipes input to stdin, but it doesn't work right.

But if I just enter

```
user$ md5
```

I can enter the word 'blue'. But how do I indicate to md5 that I'm finished entering text?

Comment: Your first attempt probably did not work correctly because you were trying to execute `blue` as a command instead of echoing it.  Try `echo blue | md5` instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

are you talking about getting an md5sum for a piece of text?

if so run the md5sum command

type your text, when finished move to a new line by pressing return

press CTRL-D to end your input.

```
 user$ md5sum
 blue
 CTRL-D
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Ctrl-D is the canonical way to terminate keyboard stdin in any shell command.

But strangely, I have an /sbin/md5 -- of indeterminate origin, but probably from OpenSSL -- on my system (Mac OS X v10.6.3) that doesn't terminate on the first Ctrl-D. It takes a second Ctrl-D to terminate it.  Same with `openssl md5`.

Comment: @Spiff: You should only need two ^D if you want to omit the final newline. If you can accept (or need) the final newline, then a single ^D on a fresh line should suffice. The EOF character (^D) flushes buffered input. If there is no buffered input, the process reading from the tty gets a zero length read (i.e. EOF). See (e.g.) [POSIX XRAT 11.1.9, EOF](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09); [VEOF in Linux termios](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios); or [EOF in FreeBSD termios](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=termios&sektion=4).

Comment: On WSL using `openssl md5` I have to press Ctrl-D 3 times.  By 2030 we should have to press it 4 times at this rate.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you need an `echo`:

```
user$ echo "blue" | md5
```

Comment: it's useless. Idea was, all input is pressed by keyboard. Problem was how to mark stream end.